# How secure is using something like `aws-sdk` (and process.env) in a react (web) app hosted on S3?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm still pretty new to doing full-stack development completely in AWS and have never really explored or attempted to exploit any of my front-end react, react-native projects.

To put it bluntly, `aws-amplify` provides a pretty thin client layer for doing Auth stuff in Cognito. But you are extremely limited compared to what you can get away with in `aws-sdk` e.g. [See this issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1324#issuecomment-487158262) where someone is attempting to list users from an identity pool in Amplify but then this commenter comes along and is just straight-up inlucding `aws-sdk` for interfacing with the `AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider`

I'm just curious how dangerous exposing or enabling something like `aws-sdk` could be from the front-end. I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea but I have no idea in this world of serverless shit these days. :/

Answer (score 0):

Just like anything else, there's a lot of it depends. As long as you're not committing your **.env** files (which can lead to mistakes) and instead you're injecting those variables through **SSM Parameter Store**. Using things like cloudformation or terraform to pull those down, you reduce your footprint and are less prone to "oops I didn't mean to commit that" errors.

If you're using ECS Fargate, ECS EC2, Lambda or any other native AWS service, there's tight coupling there already for those parameters. If you're exclusively frontend and dependent on the browser, then yes things like Amplify make this more feasible and secure.